# Divide a list into two sublists `TakeDrop`wise, but according to inconsecutive positions

Tags: list-manipulation

I can not make sure, but I have searched this website, there is not the same question as what I will ask below. If it turns out there indeed exists, please let me know, thanks a lot.

My question is not complicated, actually. Suppose I have a `List` of `Length` 32:

```
values = RandomInteger[9, 32];
```

**A baby question**

If I want to divide it into two groups, e.g., by naming that the 3rd to 6th elements are in Group I and the rest are in Group II, I can use `TakeDrop` to easily satisfy myself:

```
TakeDrop[values, {3, 6}]
```

The advantage of `TakeDrop` is that the user need not provide the information for Group II explicitly.

**The real question**

Well, what I really want to put into Group I, besides the 3rd to 6th elements, in the meanwhile includes also the 13th to 16th elements, namely, the position specification is not in a consecutive fashion. At first, I guessed `TakeDrop` maybe also to work, but did not find a way out. And what so far I can come up with is to use `Part` with `Complement`, something like:

```
{#[[{3, 4, 5, 6, 13, 14, 15, 16}]], #[[Complement[Range[32], {3, 4, 5, 6, 13, 14, 15, 16}]]]} &[values]
```

which, frankly speaking, I do not think very pretty, in that I have to write code to calculate the positions for Group II.

So, is there a way like `TakeDrop` working for my real question?

Answer (score 3):

```
ClearAll[foldTakeDrop]
foldTakeDrop =  Fold[Function[{x, y}, {Join[#, First[x]], #2} & @@ 
      TakeDrop[Last@x, y]], {{}, #}, Reverse[#2]] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
SeedRandom[1]
values = RandomInteger[9, 32]
```

> ```
> {1, 4, 0, 7, 0, 0, 8, 6, 0, 4, 1, 8, 5, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 6, 0, 2, 6, 4, 5, 
>  4, 3, 0, 1, 3, 5, 3}
> ```

```
foldTakeDrop[values, {{3, 6}, {13, 16}}]
```

> ```
> {{0, 7, 0, 0, 5, 1, 1, 1}, 
>  {1, 4, 8, 6, 0, 4, 1, 8, 3, 2, 1, 6, 0, 2, 6, 4, 5, 4, 3, 0, 1, 3, 5, 3}}
> ```

```
MapAt[Style[#, Red] &, values, List /@ Join[Range[3, 6], Range[13, 16]]]
```

[image: >]

```
foldTakeDrop[values, {{3, 6}, {13, 16}, {22, 28, 2}}]
```

> ```
> {{0, 7, 0, 0, 5, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 4, 0}, 
>  {1, 4, 8, 6, 0, 4, 1, 8, 3, 2, 1, 6, 0, 6, 5, 3, 1, 3, 5, 3}}
> ```

```
MapAt[Style[#, Red] &, values, 
 List /@ Join[Range[3, 6], Range[13, 16], Range[22, 28, 2]]]
```

[image]

**Update:** Alternative methods:

```
ClearAll[thruExtractDelete, foldPairs]

thruExtractDelete = Through[{Extract, Delete}[#, List /@ Join @@ Range @@@ #2]] &;

foldPairs = {Flatten@Reverse@#[[All, All, 1]], #[[-1, -1, -1]]} &@
    FoldPairList[TakeDrop, #, Reverse@#2, List] &;





foldPairs[values, {{3, 6}, {13, 16}}] == 
 thruExtractDelete[values, {{3, 6}, {13, 16}}] == 
  foldTakeDrop[values, {{3, 6}, {13, 16}}]
```

> ```
>   True
> ```

```
foldPairs[values, {{3, 6}, {13, 16}, {22, 28, 2}}] == 
 thruExtractDelete[values, {{3, 6}, {13, 16}, {22, 28, 2}}] == 
   foldTakeDrop[values, {{3, 6}, {13, 16}, {22, 28, 2}}]
```

> ```
>   True
> ```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer, which fortunately works more like what I want; then, unfortunately, it seems no builtin function to work.

Answer (score 2):

> Group I, besides the 3rd to 6th elements, in the meanwhile includes
>   also the 13th to 16th elements, namely, the position specification is
>   not in a consecutive fashion

If I understand you right:

```
 values=RandomInteger[9,32]
 (*{1,6,7,9,3,9,4,8,4,7,1,7,1,3,5,3,3,6,5,1,1,0,2,8,4,7,8,7,6,7,9,3}*)

  p = Join[ Range[3, 6], Range[13, 16] ];
  (*{3, 4, 5, 6, 13, 14, 15, 16}*)
```

The above are the positions of elements to delete. `Part` accepts non consecutive positions.

```
  group1 = values[[ p ]]

  (* {7, 9, 3, 9, 1, 3, 5, 3} *)
```

To remove group1 from original list, one way is to use `Delete`. But `Delete` wants positions as `{{1},{2},..}` and not as `{1,2,...}`, so add extra `{}`

```
  group2 = Delete[values, List[#] & /@ p];
  (*{1, 6, 4, 8, 4, 7, 1, 7, 3, 6, 5, 1, 1, 0, 2, 8, 4, 7, 8, 7, 6, 7, 9,  3}*)
```

And now

```
  {group1, group2}
```

gives

```
{{7, 9, 3, 9, 1, 3, 5, 3}, 
 {1, 6, 4, 8, 4, 7, 1, 7, 3, 6, 5, 1, 1, 0, 2, 8, 4, 7, 8, 7, 6, 7, 9, 3}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I think your code understands what process to undergo and can obtain the right result. But it is not exactly what I want.

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ I do not understand, It gives same result as you show. Did you try `{group1, group2}` ?

Comment: I have to apologize, maybe I did not express myself very clearly. I have added additional information. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: Yes, I believe your code can give the right result.